# From manual pull on server to Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've always deployed my apps through SSH by manually logging in and running `git pull origin master`, running migrations and pre-compiling assets.

Now i started to get more interested in Capistrano so i gave it a try, i setup a recipe with the repository pointing to github and `deploy_to` to `/home/myusername/apps/greatapp`

The current app on the server is already hooked up with Git too so i didn't know why i had to specify the github url in the recipe again, but i ran `cap deploy` which was successful.

The changes didn't apply, so out of curiosity i browsed to the app folder on the server and found out that Capistrano created folders: `shared`, `releases` and `current`. the latter contained the app, so now i have 2 copies one in `/home/myusername/apps/greatapp` and another in `/home/myusername/apps/greatapp/current`.

1. Is this how it should be? and I have to migrate user uploads to `current` and destroy the old app?
2. Does Capistrano pull the repo on my localhost then upload it through SSH or run `pull` on the server? in other words can someone outline how the deployment works?
3. Does Capistrano run `precompile:assets`?

Answer (score 0):

/releases/ is for previous versions incase you want to do cap:rollback.
/current/ as you rightly pointed out is for the current version of your app.
/shared/ is for files and folders that you want to persist between deployments, they typically get symlinked to your /current/ folder as part of your recipe.

Capistrano connects to your server in a shell and then executes the git commands on the server.

Answer (score 0):

1. Capistrano should automatically put anything in `public/system` (the rails convention for stored user-uploaded files) into the shared directory, and set up the necessary symlinks.
2. If you put in the github url, it actually fetches from your github repo.  Read https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano for more info.
3. It does, by default.